# Multiple Param with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have two components one is **AddList** component and second is **DetailList** compnent. What i am doing is there is a list of AddList component and button in every **li** . Whenever the user click on any button the respective id and name of that particualar LI is sent to **DetailList** component so that user can read more on that particular product. 
I am using react roouter and when i pass one param in the route every thing works i fine. I can console.log the respected Id `<Route exact path="/details/:id" component={DetailOffAdd} />`. But when i pass second param in route `<Route exact path="/details/:id/:name" component={DetailOffAdd} />` my component did not mount and also it does not shows any error. It also do not console the id and name i am priting in DetailList component.

Here is my **AddList**

export default class Addlist extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        posts : []
      }
    }

```
passToDetailList(id,name) {
     this.props.history.push('/details/'+id+name)
}
    render() {
      const { posts } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container" id="listOfAdd">

            <ul className="addUl">
          {
            posts.map(post => {
              return (
              <li key={post.id}>
                <button onClick={() => this.passToDetailList(post.id, post.add_title)}>VIEW</button>

                </li> 
              );
            })}


           </ul>
         </div>

**And the DetailList Component**

    export default class DetailOffAdd extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id) 
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
              Some code 
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single slug in the router path to send much more details -

```
<Route exact path="/details/:id" component={DetailOffAdd} />

let dataObj  = {
       id:1,
       name:"someProduct"
    }
let stringifyData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
```

To pass the data  -

```
passToDetailList(id,name) {
  this.props.history.push('/details/'+stringifyData)
}
```

To Get the data in details file -

```
let data  = JSON.parse(this.props.match.params.id);
console.log(data) // here is your full data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a '/', try changing your passToDetailList to this:

```
this.props.history.push(`/details/${id}/${name}`)
```

Comment: I still get a blank page and nothing prints in the console. But the url is this ```http://localhost:3000/details/2/SECONDADD```