# Open the new component on click of search Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

After user enters the search query in search box, i want the user to navigation to some other page, say "/market" component, with the search query, like this: **https://localhost:8080/market?searchString=asdf**. Can anyone please help me with this! I am not sure how to start with it.

```
<Search
              onKeyPress={(event) => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                  this.onSearch(event.target.value);
                }
              }}
              placeHolderText= "Search"
              type="text"
            />
```

Method:

```
 onSearch(searchString) {
        if (searchString) {
          //performSearch
        }
      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Comment: i dont see , they are passing param anywhere in above example. I want to pass the parameter along with navigating

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983051/multiple-param-with-react-router/61983141#61983141

Comment: can you help me with what to set in props to use this.props.history.push / this.props.router.push. Because i m getting, this.props.history is undefined in below code: interface props  extends RouteComponentProps<any> { history: RouteComponentProps.history;}

Comment: Have you wrapped your component with `withRouter` HOC?